Is it possible to expose all files in specific folder in LiveShare?
I want to share all any files or folders in specific folder (or root project folder) in VSCode LiveShare.
There just ignore settings but I want to like "include" files to always show files to guests.
I've tried look for how in GitHub or google, though doesn't find one.
